# cannot import name 'MDToolbar' from 'kivymd.uix.toolbar'

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I am trying to run the below code,

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFillRoundFlatIconButton, MDFillRoundFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar

class ConverterApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = MDScreen()

    self.toolbar = MDToolbar(title = 'Binary to Decimal')
    self.toolbar.pos_hint = {'top':1}
    screen.add_widget(self.toolbar)
    return screen 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ConverterApp().run()
```

But seeing a output error, which is

```
    from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
    ImportError: cannot import name 'MDToolbar' from 'kivymd.uix.toolbar'
```

I even searched on google, regarding this module error, but didn't get the required answer.
Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: Try using `MDTopAppBar` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use MDTopAppBar instead - https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/toolbar/ `MDToolbar' has been deprecated since version 1.0.0.